# Homestead box is stuck in emergency mode

Tags: boot, bash, virtualbox

I'm running a Homestead box on a Windows 10 host using VirtualBox.  Everything was working fine when accessing this VM using Git Bash.  Then, I wanted to try accessing it using VirtualBox.  When the VM was powered up in VirtualBox (instead of using Git Bash and the vagrant commands), a screen like this came up:
[image]
(Note that this is not my actual screen as I didn't capture a screen shot of it at that point.  This screenshot was found online.)
  I didn't know what to enter for a password so I shut the VM down within VirtualBox.  After that point is when the problem started.  It won't open to the screen shown above in VirtualBox.  Instead it gives a "You are in emergency mode" message after outputting some lines in the terminal.  After reading some posts online I issued the `sudo blkid` and the `ca ../etc/fstab` commands.  See below.  However, I couldn't make sense of the other posts and how they apply to this problem.  Is this issue repairable?  If so, how?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @EthanC No, I haven't been able to resolve it.   I did some more reading on forums mostly, to try and get it running again.  The 4/7/2019 post by "kansasnobb" in this link https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2318779&p=13466943#post13466943 was particularly useful.  I was able to issue the first 3 commands recommended in that post but the VM hung after the third one so it was necessary to shut it down.  When it powered back up a different error appeared than it had been giving.  Now it is stuck in BusyBox.  Even with the exit command is given, it will not exit.